# What is the socket that connects to my tcp server infinitely on Azure AKS?

Tags: node.js, sockets, kubernetes, tcp, azure-aks

I created a clean Node.js project:

```js
import * as net from "net";

net.createServer(socket => {
  console.log('new client', socketToString(socket));
  socket.on('data', data => console.log(data));
  socket.on('end', () => console.log('client close', socketToString(socket)));
})
  .listen(20202, () => console.log('listening on 20202'));

function socketToString(socket: net.Socket): string {
  return `(local)=${socket.localAddress}:${socket.localPort} (remote)=${socket.remoteAddress}:${socket.remotePort}`;
}
```

In helm chart:

```
service:
  type: LoadBalancer

spec:
  ports:
  - port: 20202
    targetPort: 20202
    protocol: TCP
    name: tcp-server
```

Using Azure Dev Spaces I pushed my project to my cluster and in the logs I can see that immediately a client connects to my server and disconnects after few seconds without sending any data. When it disconnects immediately a new socket connects. It goes infinitely.

```
listening on 20202
new client (local)=::ffff:10.244.0.141:20202 (remote)=::ffff:10.244.0.1:19114
client close (local)=undefined:undefined (remote)=::ffff:10.244.0.1:19114
new client (local)=::ffff:10.244.0.141:20202 (remote)=::ffff:10.244.0.1:52075
client close (local)=undefined:undefined (remote)=::ffff:10.244.0.1:52075
new client (local)=::ffff:10.244.0.141:20202 (remote)=::ffff:10.244.0.1:63285
client close (local)=undefined:undefined (remote)=::ffff:10.244.0.1:63285
```

With service type ClusterIP it doesn't happen. Dynamic or static IP doesn't make a difference. Using *kubectl describe service* I can see:

```
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.0.86.248
LoadBalancer Ingress:     20.54.185.111
Port:                     tcp-server  20202/TCP
TargetPort:               20202/TCP
NodePort:                 tcp-server  30132/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.141:20202
```

So *Endpoints:* matches the local IP of the socket. What is causing it? Is this some kind of a loopback? Is Azure Dev Spaces causing it?

// EDIT

*kubectl describe pod* (IP has changed as it is a new instance):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UyjvthjGCwmwaG9nMH_UFyWT3TiMek0-

Comment: By any chance, did you define any [health probe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-add-health-probes)?

Comment: From what I can see in the "azds prep" generated chart, probes are disabled "probes: enabled: false"

Comment: What do you you see when you run `kubectl describe <your-app-pod> -n <your-namespace>`?

Comment: I added the command result to the question under // EDIT. Not much there though...